# Particle Engine much, much slower on device than on Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've implemented a particle engine for a game for iPad. On the iPad Simulator I get a very good framerate with >500 particles (way more than I need). On an iPad itself however, I get completely different results. With just 10 particles (I need a few more than that) I only get a very poor framerate...

As a basis I've taken this tutorial to implement my Particle Emitter class: http://www.71squared.com/en/article/806/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-8-particle-emitter
(uses OpenGL ES 1)

Because I use OpenGL ES 2.0, I wrote my own render method:

```
- (void) renderParticles:(RenderMode)renderMode ofParticleEmitter:(ParticleEmitter*)particleEmitter xOffset:(int)xoffset yOffset:(int)yoffset
{

PointSprite *vertices = [particleEmitter getVertices];

for (int p = 0; p < particleEmitter.particleCount; p++) {

    CC3GLMatrix *modelView = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
    // Translate the Modelviewmatrix
    [modelView populateFromTranslation:CC3VectorMake(_cameraX, _cameraY, -5.0)];


    [modelView translateByX:vertices[p].x + xoffset];
    [modelView translateByY:vertices[p].y + yoffset];
    [modelView translateByZ:101.0];  

    [modelView scaleByX:2.0];
    [modelView scaleByY:2.0];

    glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniformT, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [particleEmitter getTexture]);

    // Create and Bind a rectangular VBO
    [self calcCharacterVBOwithCols:1 rows:1 currentCol:1 currentRow:1];    

    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlotT, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlotT);

    // Fragment Shader value
    float opacity = 1.0;
    glUniform1f(_opacity, opacity);

    // Normal render, add Texture coordinates

    // Activate Texturing Pipeline and Bind Texture
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordSlot);


    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(IndicesLayer)/sizeof(IndicesLayer[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordSlot);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlotT);

    [self destroyCharacterVBO];
}
}
```

Did I miss some essential point on particles? What can I do better to get a better framerate on the device?

Comment: did you have many NSLog's in your code, that spams to the console?

Comment: The simulator does not, as far as I know, simulate the processor speed of the actual devices. So if your computer is more powerful than a device (Which is almost certainly is,) then performance will be much better on the simulator. You should always do performance testing on the device itself.

Comment: Only during the initialization of the App (loading Textures, Sounds, etc.). During the runloop itself there are no NSLog's spammed to the console.

Comment: Simulator works at speed of your Mac CPU - way faster than iPad. Simulator's GPU is also way faster than GPU of iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been assigning the particle texture again and again for every single  particle even though they all use the same texture.

So by binding the texture

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [particleEmitter getTexture]);
```

before looping over all the particles I get a much faster frame rate that is comparable to the simulator.